# Regex: how to put a substring within parenthesis according to negative lookahead & lookbehind?

Tags: python, regex

my goal is to put a substring within parenthesis according to some specific rules.

For example, here is a text:

`text = 'cake OR ice cream'`

And my goal is to transform this original text into this:

`'cake OR (ice AND cream)'`

As you can see, the ultimate goal is to preserve some Boolean logics within the text.

First step is to add the `TO_PARENTHESIS` that we will use as some sort of anchor.
I can do it using negative lookbehind & lookahead:

```
import regex as re

text = re.sub(r'(?<!OR|AND|NOT|\(|\)|")(\s+)(?!OR|AND|NOT|\(|\)|")', r' TO_PARENTHESIS ', text)
```

This will find empty spaces & replace those with `TO_PARENTHESIS` but only the ones that are between two non-boolean keywords (and non-special characters).

Here is what we get:

`cake OR ice TO_PARENTHESIS cream`

Now, my question is, how do I put parenthesis at the very specific points, to have something like this:

`cake OR (ice TO_PARENTHESIS cream)`

I tried:
`(?<!OR|AND|NOT|\(|\)|")(.*TO_PARENTHESIS.*)(?!OR|AND|NOT|\(|\)|")` but this will select the entire text & not just the `ice TO_PARENTHESIS cream` as expected.

So two questions:

- How to select the correct group?
- How to replace that selected group by itself plus the two parenthesis?

And last step would be to replace the `TO_PARENTHESIS` with `AND` to finally get our `'cake OR (ice AND cream)'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a pattern to match `TO_PARENTHESIS` surrounded by a word, and then in the callback of `re.sub` place the full match between parenthesis and replace TO_PARENTHESIS by `AND`

```
\w+(?:\s+TO_PARENTHESIS\s+\w+)+
```

The pattern matches:

- `\w+` Match 1+ word characters
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\s+TO_PARENTHESIS` Match whitespace chars and `TO_PARENTHESIS`
  - `\s+\w+` Match whitespace chars and 1+ word chars
- `)+` Close non capture group and repeat 1 or more times for multiple matches

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f2A3xz/1)

```
import regex as re

text = 'cake OR ice cream please'
text = re.sub(r'(?<!OR|AND|NOT|\(|\)|")\s+(?!OR|AND|NOT|\(|\)|")', r' TO_PARENTHESIS ', text)
text = re.sub(
    r"\w+\s+TO_PARENTHESIS\s+\w+",
    lambda x: "(" + x.group().replace("TO_PARENTHESIS", "AND") + ")",
    text
)
print(text)
```

Output

```
cake OR (ice AND cream)
```

See a [Python demo](https://tio.run/##bY5Na8JAEIbv@yumc9ldEnLpTVpEUKiXpMQcA2WNg4Yas0xWjLD/PY7SHiyd0/B@PLz@Gg796XWa2s73HIBpTyO4QR6lAo0B3kE37pugKKFtCBom1@lfiykbzlvD2szfXooyLvJlzIsq1ibWNqKth8TM/zN0CqyhKr4@F@Uqrz5Wm/UGRLxz7R@6AjnG@iKsmRCfWyKIYxNMH7mj67Y7B@MM0CAkMGZ77s/e2IzJH11DBp/7mALKOrQSRvtDuQ9QVnluT8E8Nk3TDQ).

---

If the input is

> cake OR ice cream please

The output will be

```
cake OR (ice AND cream AND please)
```

If you want to do a single replacement only instead of multiple, you can shorten the pattern to:

```
\w+\s+TO_PARENTHESIS \w+
```

Comment: @RobZ I get `cake OR (ice AND cream AND please)` as output. See [this link](https://tio.run/##bY5Na8JAEIbv@yumc9ldEnLxJi0iVGgvicQcA2WNgw1NzDJZaYT973GU9mDpnIb34@H1l/A5nBbz3PZ@4ABMR5rAjfIoFWgK8AK6cV8ERQltQ9AwuR58R24k/Ztgysbz3rA2q@enoozr/DXmRRVrE2sb0dZjYlb/GToF1lAVH9t1ucmrt83ufQci3rj2D12BHGP9LaylEB9bIohjE0zvuc71@4ODaQloEBKYsiMPZ29sxuQ715DBxz6mgLIOrYTR/lBuA5RVnttTMPdN83wF)

Comment: My bad I was using the code in SO instead of the one in the link

Comment: Is there a way to use lookahead and lookbehind instead of w+? Meaning "take this group around TO_PARENTHESIS up until you see a NOT or AND or OR".

Comment: @RobZ You might use a tempered pattern to not cross any of the alternatives and the match TO_PARENTHESIS. See https://regex101.com/r/4eRd1V/1

Answer (score 1):

Maybe...

```
import re

# starting string
text = 'cake OR ice cream'

# first pattern that finds the space between two lowercase letters (assuming it's always OR, AND, NOT, etc.)
pattern_1 = re.compile(r'([a-z])\s([a-z])') #replace with \1 AND \2

# capture the word (via a boundary) before the AND and the word after the AND
pattern_2 = re.compile(r'(\b\w+\b\sAND\s\b\w+)') #replace with (\1)

# show the starting text
print(text)

# make 'cake OR ice cream' into 'cake OR ice AND cream'
text = pattern_1.sub(r'\1 AND \2', text)

# make 'cake OR ice AND cream' into 'cake OR (ice AND cream)'
text = pattern_2.sub(r'(\1)', text)
print(text)
```

Input:

```
cake OR ice cream
```

Output:

```
cake OR (ice AND cream)
```